# Something wrong with Frameworks in PIL

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

When trying to install PIL on mac osx I do `sudo python setup.py install` and get everything right but the following output. Has this happened to anyone before?

```
running build_ext
--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
building '_imaging' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/libImaging
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers -IlibImaging -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_imaging.o
_imaging.c:3017: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
_imaging.c:3077: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
_imaging.c:3017: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
_imaging.c:3077: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
_imaging.c:3281: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
_imaging.c:3017: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
_imaging.c:3077: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccltKqHA.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473896/failed-to-build-pil-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion ?

I will also suggest that you use macports or brew to install PIL instead of "sudo python setup.py install".

Comment: there must be a way to use PIL no?

Comment: try `pip install pillow` - I'm a convert!

Comment: where does pip install it? what directory? It needs to be in site-packages so that I can use django

Comment: @YujiTomita I dont have pip...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
2. `brew install python mysql`
3. `easy_install pip`
4. `pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`
5. `echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh > /dev/null" >> ~/.bash_profile`
6. `source ~/.bash_profile`
7. `mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages <your env name>`
8. `pip install django pillow`

Comment: why not just ``brew install pil``?

Comment: i did but I also needed to `ln -s` the installation to the site-packages dir

Comment: jterrace, there's virtualenv to keep your python stuff in shape

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, be sure to [set your architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366882/installing-pil-on-os-x-snow-leopard-w-xcode4-no-ppc-support), and second, use [pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) instead of PIL since it's an actively maintained fork of PIL. i.e.

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" sudo pip install pillow
```

If you're environment is all mucked up from your first attempt, here are some suggestions on where to [find and remove old PIL files](http://markliu.me/2011/aug/20/installing-libjpeg-and-pil-on-osx-snow-leopard-wit/).